# scala yield in 'match' scope expects 'case' clauses

Tags: xml, scala

I have a code that parses some products from xml with **products**.. there is one part that matches, and puts the result to **products** val:

```
 val products = 

  for (event <- reader) {    

     event match {

        case EvElemStart(_, "product", meta, _) =>

                  product = new Product()

                  product.title = meta("title").toString
                  product.description = meta("description").toString

        case EvElemEnd(_, "product") =>
                  yield product                  // <--

        case _ =>

     }

}
```

It expects "case" after **yield**. 
 Why?

And how it could be done in scala way?

---

Another try:

```
val products =   

   for (event <- reader) {

          var title = "";
          var description = "";

          event match {

            case EvElemStart(_, "product", meta, _) =>

              title = meta("title").toString
              description = meta("title").toString

            case EvElemEnd(_, "product") =>

            case _ =>

          }

   }  yield new Product("", "");  // <---
```

Compiler says that it expects "}" just before **yield**

Comment: [`yield` is not a `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid/1334822#1334822)

Answer (score 2):

`expr match case { ... }` is an expression. It usually returns a value, though it can be `Unit`. In that case it acts more like a statement.

`for (...) yield {...}` is also an expression. In your case, it will return an iterator (since reader is an iterator). So that would compile (though not do what you want):

```
for (event <- reader) yield {
  new Product("", "")
}

for {
  event <- reader
  product = new Product("", "")
} yield product

for {
  event <- reader
} yield {
  val product = new Product("", "")
  product
}
```

Note that braces can be replaced with parenthesis, which changes how semicolons/statement endings are inferred. In general if you need multiple lines, use braces.

This would compile too:

```
for (event <- reader) yield {
  val product = event match {
     case EvElemStart(_, "product", meta, _) =>
       val title = meta("title").toString 
       val description = meta("title").toString
       Some(Product(title, description) // return some product 
     case _ =>
       None                             // return none
  }
  // product is a value of type Option[Product]
  product // last expression of a { ... } block will be the return value of block
}
```

It would return an iterator yielding values like this: `Some(Product(...)), None, None, Some(Product(...))`.